# Remove item from category collection in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, category, collection, catalog

I have a category collection in Magento 1.9

This is my code :-

```
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => 4))
    ->addIsActiveFilter()
    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {

       $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());

       $categories->removeItemByKey($cat->getId);
       echo '<pre>';
       //echo $cat->getIsActive();
       print_r($categories->getData());
       exit;
    }
```

I need to remove the element corresponding to the current categoryId from the collection in the current loop so that when I use the same collection anywhere after the first loop I do not get the same category again.

But when I do `$categories->removeItemByKey($cat->getId)` it does not work. It does not remove the corresponding id element from the categories collection.

Am I doing something wrong or does `removeItemByKey()` not work for category collection and I have to do something else.

I am trying to find this for 5 hours but to no avail.

Comment: better you can collect needed categories or get collection using neq of respective category which is you want to remove.

Comment: Not understand what exactly you want to do . Can you please little describe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => 4))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => {set you category id here}))
    ->addIsActiveFilter()
    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
echo $categories->getSelect();
foreach ($categories as $cat) {


    echo '<pre>';
    //echo $cat->getIsActive();
    print_r($categories->getData());
    exit;
}
```

OR you can exclude that by particular category ID

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => {set you category id here}))
    ->addIsActiveFilter()
    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
echo $categories->getSelect();
foreach ($categories as $cat) {

    if($cat->getId() != 5)
    echo '<pre>';
    //echo $cat->getIsActive();
    print_r($categories->getData());
    exit;
}
```

Here is the clone feature.

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');

$categoriesCollection = clone $categories;

$categoriesCollectionFilter = $categoriesCollection
        ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => 3))
    ->addIsActiveFilter()
    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC')
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => 5));
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($categoriesCollectionFilter->getData());
echo "<br><br><br><br>";
$categoriesOther = $categories->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => 3))
    ->addIsActiveFilter()
    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
    print_r($categoriesOther->getData());
exit;
```

Comment: I need to remove the element corresponding to the current categoryId from the collection in the current loop so that when I use the same collection anywhere after the first loop I do not get the same category again. Sorry I did not explain properly. I edited the question to explain this properly.

Comment: @SushantGurjar, I have updated answer.